# Firebase Cloud Functions check is snapshot.exists() error

Tags: node.js, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

When I try to run a function

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.checkPostsRef = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {

    const postId = 'foo'

    admin.database().ref('/posts/' + postId).once('value', snapshot => {

        if !snapshot.exists() {
            console.log("+++++++++ post does not exist +++++++++") // I want this to print
            return
        }
    });
});
```

I keep getting an error of `Parsing error: Unexpected token snapshot`:

[image]

Once I **comment out** if `snapshot.exists() { .... }` **everything works fine**.

I'm following this [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot) that says there is an `.exists()` function, so why am I having this issue?

[image]

Comment: Hey Lance. Good to see in the answer below that you got it working. But it looks like you now actually removed the problem from your question too. Can you revert that, so that the question shows the problem, and you answer shows how you solved it. On the actual problem: in your original code, the problem was cause by missing `()` around the `if` condition. In Swift, `if !snapshot.exists()` is valid, but in JavaScript it must be `if (!snapshot.exists())`. Note that this has nothing to do with the return statement, but is purely about the `()` around the condition of your `if`.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I changed the question back to the original code and I also removed the semi-colons which I didn't have in the original question and added as edits. You're right, it makes sense to keep it as it originally was so that if the next person runs into the issue, they can see my mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good to see how you got it working Lance. Your conclusion on the `return` being the cause is wrong though, so I'll explain the actual cause below.

The problem is in this code:

```
if !snapshot.exists() ...
```

In JavaScript you **must** have parenthesis around the complete condition of an `if` statement. So the correct syntax is:

```
if (!snapshot.exists()) ...
```

In Swift those outer parenthesis are optional, but in JavaScript (and al other C based languages that I know of), they are required.

Answer (score 0):

turns out it was the `return;` statement that was causing the problem. I had to use an `if-else` statement instead.

**EDIT** As @FrankvanPuffelen pointed out in the comments below the question and his answer, this issue wasn't about the `return` statement, it was about the way i initially had the `!snapshot.exists()`. Because it wasn't wrapped in parentheses `(!snapshot.exists())` which was causing the problem. So it wasn't the `return` statement, I know very little Javascript and **used the wrong syntax**.

```
if (!snapshot.exists()) {

    console.log("+++++++++ post does not exist +++++++++");

} else {

    console.log("--------- post exists ---------");
}
```

FYI I'm a native Swift developer and in Swift you don't need to wrap anything in parentheses.  In Swift you can do this:

```
let ref = Database.database().reference().child("post").child("foo")
ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

    if !snapshot.exists() {
        print("+++++++++ post does not exist +++++++++")
        return
    }
})
```